# Microsoft Edge - Angular Input Bug?

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

This works on Chrome, FF and Safari. In Edge when I left click in the input field, it seems that on the `mouseup` event the input loses focus and the cursor leaves the input to some random element above. I can tab into this input and I can right click to bring up the copy/paste menu, click elsewhere on the page, and the cursor stays in the input.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="prod in product" ng-if='ngCart.itemInCart(prod.id)'>
  <div id="{{prod.id}}" count="{{prod.count}}" class="card-info col-md-12" ng-click="showInfo(prod.id)">
    <div ng-if="prod.count == 0" class="info-form pink-active col-md-12">
       <div ng-if="prod.id == '11'" class="col-md-12">
           <input type="text"/>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this? Again, it works perfectly in other browsers. Client is using Edge, so I have to fix this.

UPDATE: If I left click in the input and move the mouse outside the input before I release the left button, the cursor stays in the input, again the `mouseup` event is what's breaking this. Thanks!